# ok to have high average EC2 CPU load on AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

We've recently downgraded a batch processing instance in AWS to reduce costs. The CPU now is averaging about 70%. However it still seems to be coping with the load.

Is there any issue with running an instance continuously at high average CPU load?

Is there any kind of fair use policy that would come into play.

The instance type is in the r5 class, so CPU credits aren't an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue with doing this, if your performance is adequate.  You are paying for exclusive use of the CPU and memory allocated to the virtual machine.

CPU resources are not shared across VMs on any class of EC2 instance -- except possibly to some not-fully-documented extent on the burstable "t"-class instances -- and even those do not restrict your usage by either technology or policy if you have available CPU credits or you use the t2/t3-unlimited feature.

Comment: Almost certainly they are shared on "t"-class instances, otherwise those instances would make no sense.